# How to change the font according to selection in text tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

How to change the font of the selected text in tkinter? I have checked the web, but I did not get any results. I want the fonts in a `ComboBox` of `tkinter.ttk`.

Please help!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66287864/exception-in-tkinter-callback-but-still-working) question with free code for you

Comment: Well If you want I can write you a code for that. But that would be only when you tell me what exactly do you want? You want a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```py
text_widget.tag_add("font_1", *map(str, text_widget.tag_ranges("sel")))
text_widget.tag_config("font_1", font=...)
```

That will change the font of the selected text. If you bind to the `ComboBox` changing and run the script, it should work.